# How to match strings from an XML file using batch and assign to variable?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have an XML file (generated by a third party tool) which is of format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ROOT test_count="22" test_fail_count="1" test_pass_count="21".......</ROOT>
```

All the content is in one line of the file with name `Report.xml`.

I have been trying to write a batch script

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "Report="
for /f "delims=" %%x in (Report.xml) do set "Report=!Report! %%x"
REm set /p Report=< %Results_File%
echo report is !Report!
call:parseVal !Report!
exit/b

:parseVal
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set val="%~1"
echo %val%
echo !val!|findstr /rc:"test_count=.[0-9]*." >nul || (
    echo !val!
    EndLocal
    exit /b
)

rem ..
```

Basically I am trying to grab values for `test_count(22)`, `test_fail_count(1)` and `test_pass_count(21)` from the XML file.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Why does it have to be a batch file?

Comment: unfortunately , that is a requirement in my case, i.e it cannot be *.sh , however if there a good option in Perl or other scripting language I might be able to consider it.

Comment: Can't it be JavaScript? From what I remember Windows used to have this "scripting host" thing. Isn't that still there?

Comment: Yep, looks like WSH is available from Win98 onwards (Win10 still has it): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q42057260.txt"
SET "testcount="
SET "testfailcount="
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET "xmlline=%%a"
 CALL :process
)

ECHO test count=%testcount% test fail count=%testfailcount%

GOTO :EOF

:process
:: dispose of awkward characters
SET "xmlline=%xmlline:?= %"
SET "xmlline=%xmlline:>= %"
SET "xmlline=%xmlline:<= %"
CALL :select %xmlline%
GOTO :EOF

:select
IF /i "%~1"=="" GOTO :EOF
IF DEFINED testcount IF DEFINED testfailcount GOTO :EOF
IF /i "%~1"=="test_count" SET /a testcount=%~2
IF /i "%~1"=="test_fail_count" SET /a testfailcount=%~2
SHIFT
GOTO select

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q42057260.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Read the file to `%%a` and transfer to `xmlline`.

Use `:process` to remove awkward characters (those with a special meaning to `cmd`) by replacing each with a space, then pass the resultant line to `:select` as a parameter-list.

look at each parameter in turn, stripping quotes. When the target strings appear, set their storage variables to the following value. When both values are assigned, bail out.

and report results.

Comment: for some reason the code does'nt move past the "for  loop". it exits out and prints                                                                                                           test count= test fail count=

Comment: Batch syntax is very specific. It's best to cut-and-paste. If you were to add a line `echo "%%~1` on a new line directly under `:select`, then you should see the routine examining each element provided in turn.

Comment: that worked. it was a typo on my part thanks a lot !

Comment: For some reason , the code isnt working again.  I copy pasted into notepad++ coult that be the problem?

Comment: @mofi: The options parameter merely states that the string `contains one or more keywords` - although the examples use a space-separator. `cmd` appears to see whether the option is contained in the option string, deletes any option found from the string before checking for the next option. Hence `"delims=#usebackq"` is valid; `usebackq` is detected first & eliminated, `#` is used as `delims`. I habitually use the `delims` option last to circumvent typos. Would `"delims=#usebackq"` & `"delims=# usebackq"` act differently? I treat the space as optional & agree it's clearer but more typing.

Comment: @OP: I can't say for notepad++ - I use editplus. Since the code worked, I can only suggest that some formatting has taken place and all that can be done is careful comparison or perhaps giving some clue as to the manner in which it no longer works. Perhaps if you have a copy of the "working" version, you could compare it with the newer version using `fc` and see what the differences are. Perhaps for instance "smart" quotes have been substituted for straight quotes - can be difficult to see...

Answer (score 0):

Provided the structure and order of Report.xml is constant this could do (cmd line)

```
for /f "tokens=5,6 delims=<> " %A in (Report.xml) Do @Set %A&Set %B
```

Sample output with your Report.xml

```
> set test
test_count="22"
test_fail_count="1"
```