# How to extract values from an XML file with no newline characters (very long single line)?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to extract values for `test_count`, `test_fail_count`, `test_pass_count` from an XML file. This XML file has just one very long line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ROOT test_count="22" test_fail_count="1" test_pass_count="21".......</ROOT>
```

[Magoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2128947/magoo) helped me with the script, see his answer on my previous question
[How to match strings from an XML file using batch and assign to variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42057590/3074564)

This script worked initially. But when I incorporated this into my larger overall script, it failed. And I have not been able getting this script working again as expected since making this modification.

Any thoughts on how to debug this?

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\Report.xml"
SET "testcount="
SET "testfailcount="
echo forloop
FOR /f "usebackqdelims= " %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET "xmlline=%%a"
 CALL :process
)

ECHO test count=%testcount% test fail count=%testfailcount%

GOTO :EOF

:process
 echo in process
:: dispose of awkward characters
SET "xmlline=%xmlline:?= %"
SET "xmlline=%xmlline:>= %"
SET "xmlline=%xmlline:<= %"
CALL :select %xmlline%
GOTO :EOF

:select
echo in select
IF /i "%~1"=="" GOTO :EOF
IF DEFINED testcount IF DEFINED testfailcount GOTO :EOF
IF /i "%~1"=="test_count" SET /a testcount=%~2
IF /i "%~1"=="test_fail_count" SET /a testfailcount=%~2
SHIFT
GOTO select

GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: `any thoughts on how to debug this?` - turn `echo on`

Comment: standalone it succeeded, btu incorporated it fails, so that tells you more or less where to look. For more details, try to find out and describe what actually happens, what behaviour do you see, any errors, unexpected output, etcetera.

Comment: Without doing an exact like for like check, the code you have posted appears to be admitted working code. Your question states that the incorporation of that code to your existing code is the issue. We therefore need to see the code as incorporated. We cannot debug code we haven't seen.

Comment: Why not use a scripting language that can read and write XML? Vbscript, Jscript and Powershell are all available on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

try the [**xpath.bat**](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/xpath.bat) - it can extract values from xml files by an xpath expression and does not require installation of external tools:

```
call xpath.bat "report.xml" "//ROOT/@test_count"
call xpath.bat "report.xml" "//ROOT/@test_fail_count"
```

As in the metadata is pointed that file should be `utf-8` you can check the encodings of the files on both machines.

Comment: Since OP already had a working script, and the incorporation was what failed, I'm not sure if this practically link-only answer to another tool is going to help much.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for not anymore working code is in the command line

```
FOR /f "usebackqdelims= " %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
```

There is a space character after the equal sign which results in splitting the line read from XML file up into multiple tokens using the space character as delimiter. So instead of getting entire XML file contents assigned to loop variable `a`, just the string up to first space character is assigned to the loop variable. For that reason the environment variable `xmlline` gets assigned just `<?xml` instead of the entire line read from XML file.

Change the line to

```
FOR /f "usebackq delims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
```

There is no space after equal sign, but one between `usebackq` and `delims=`.

Or use the command line below as [Magoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2128947/magoo) posted in his answer with no space after equal sign, but also no space between the two options `usebackq` and `delims=`.

```
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
```

Magoo explained in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42057260/42057590#comment71378168_42057590) also why the space character between the two options `usebackq` and `delims=` is not really necessary, but which I suggest to add for easier reading the options.

`usebackq` results in interpreting the file name enclosed in double quotes as file name and not as string to split up into tokens.

`delims=` with no characters specified after equal sign disables default splitting up of line read from file on spaces and horizontal tabs.

Open a command prompt window, run `for /?` and read the output help pages for help on `for /F` and its options.